# How to post/upload a file from a client application to MVC Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post, file-upload

I would like to `post/upload` my `log.csv` file from client(mobile) application to my server. My `MVC4` web application is running on `IIS7` environment.

I'm not sure how to set `MVC controller's parameters` and also how to post my file to MVC web application.

My mobile application is developed by `C# with unity3D`.

Please give me some hints!

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a file in Asp.Net MVC application is very easy.

- The posted file is automatically available as a `HttpPostedFileBase`
  `parameters` in the `action of the controller`.
- For uploading a file on the server you required to have a `file input
  control with in html form` having encoding type set to
  `multipart/form-data`.
- The default encoding type of a form is
  application/x-www-form-urlencoded and this is no sufficient for
  posting a large amount of data to server.

[How to do it.. Step By Step Explained Here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/WKNQ120113-How-to-upload-a-file-in-MVC4.html)

Comment: I don't use http page to uploads a file. The client application automatically uploads log.csv file periodically. As I understand, I don'd have a form to post, is there any ways to set them programmatically?

Comment: you need to write `service` or `schedule task` to post the file from your Client machine to server. It should be periodically or scheduled. Means the service should get installed in client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Put a file input onto your page, this will allow the user to select a file to upload (ensure you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`):

```
<form action="Url To Your Action Method here" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile"/>
<form />
```

And then make an action method which receives the file in your MVC application:

```
//ensure the name of the parameter is the same as the name of the input
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReceiveFile(HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
{
}
```